# How to view bash history executed by PC1 on PC2 by way of Ant sshexec

Tags: bash, ant, history, ant-contrib

there are currently 2 PCs, PC1 and PC2.
I have an Ant script on PC1, the script will execute bash commands on PC2 using sshexec task, the snippet may like the following:

```
<sshexec 
 host="${IPofPC2}"
 username="${USERofPC2}"
 password="${PASSofPC2}"
 command='echo "Hello World!"'
 trust="true"></sshexec>
```

in practice the command is a complex one, I give `echo "Hello World!"` for an example.

I want to see what exactly the command is that have executed on PC2, but I don't know how to.
I googled and find `.bash_history` will save the remotely executed commands by one login using ssh-like terminal.

It seems this may help, but tried with no success, the `.bash_history` file won't record commands executed by sshexec task remotely.

So SOS, please help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
#/etc/syslog.conf
!sshd
*.*     /var/log/sshd.log
```

**Attachment:**

$cat /var/log/sshd.log

> Dec  8 17:36:29 brownshen
>   launchproxy[1373]:
>   /usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper:
>   Connection from: 10.224.105.186 on
>   port: 4090 Dec  8 17:36:30 brownshen
>   sshd[1376]: in pam_sm_authenticate():
>   Failed to determine Kerberos principal
>   name. Dec  8 17:36:30 brownshen
>   sshd[1374]: Accepted
>   keyboard-interactive/pam for zhouvega
>   from 10.224.105.186 port 4090 ssh2 Dec
>   8 17:36:30 brownshen
>   com.apple.SecurityServer[23]: Session
>   0x3096eb created Dec  8 17:36:30
>   brownshen
>   com.apple.SecurityServer[23]: Session
>   0x3096eb attributes 0x20 Dec  8
>   17:36:30 brownshen
>   com.apple.SecurityServer[23]: Session
>   0x3096eb dead Dec  8 17:36:30
>   brownshen
>   com.apple.SecurityServer[23]: Killing
>   auth hosts Dec  8 17:36:30 brownshen
>   com.apple.SecurityServer[23]: Session
>   0x3096eb destroyed

Comment: If login using ssh terminal(like putty) the .bash_history does record the commands that executed if check from PC2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/4722-ssh-command-logging.html

My first thought was that you could change the shell specified in passwd to be a shell-wrapper that logs all input, but I think the sshd approach is better.

And, unless you have a good reason to (user input?) you should use SSH keys for auto-logins instead of saving passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, I tried the solution but it does not work for me, which it does not log commands. BTW, I'm using Mac OSX, is that a matter?

Comment: That solution you supplied does not work for the Ant sshexec target. It doesn't record the commands executed, but the connection information. I'm thinking whether Ant sshexec target runs in ssh way. Also, only sudo commands logged if I login via PuTTY. Is there any mistake in my syslog.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that your script is actually being executed by Bash and not `sh`. Then, add these to the beginning of your script:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history 
set -o history
```

Choose a different file to save the history separately from the user's interactive history. You can use `set -o history` to turn history saving on and `set +o history` to turn it off. You can use this selectively to only save parts of the script.

Add this at the end of your script to write the in-memory history to the file:

```
history -w
```

Note that the `HISTSIZE` variable affects how many lines of history are stored in memory. The default is 500 which could be quickly filled by an executing script. The `HISTFILESIZE` variable also defaults to 500 and the same issue applies. You may need to set these variables to larger values in your script and set `HISTFILESIZE' also in the user's startup file (e.g.`~/.bashrc`) so it doesn't get truncated during interactive use if you're using the same history file.

Note that for some uses, instead of using history you can use `set -x` to turn on tracing and capture stdout to a file.

Comment: Sorry that my script is not on the machine which hosts the history file. Indeed, I run Ant script which call sshexec target that runs the actually bash commands.

Comment: @user435657: I'm not familiar with Ant, but can't you send the commands I've shown to the remote machine so they're executed there?